# jqgrid date column, show only the date

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter

I'm trying to show only the date part in my jqgrid column

The columns is defined like

```
{name:'Ingreso',formatter:"date",formatoptions:{srcformat:"d/m/Y H:i A",newformat:"ShortDate"}
```

The datatype is local

The locale is 'es' and the jqgrid version is 4.3.1

The date is showed 08/04/2012 08:42 p.m. (day 8, month 4) and i like to show 08/04/2012

I'm using this link as reference: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I can't reproduce your problem. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShortDate.htm). Additionally I'll recommend you to use [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format of the date in the input data.

Comment: Hi, I will investigate a bit more ... but one strange thing is that in your demo I see the date 4/8/2012 while in your source the srcformat is d/m/Y

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez: You use `newformat:"ShortDate"` and `grid.locale-es.js` contains `"n/j/Y"`. I just verified [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.es-ES.js#L66) that it's wrong format for Spain and wrong for Spanish (Argentina) see [here](https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/lib/cultures/globalize.culture.es-AR.js#L64). If you would use `newformat: 'd/m/Y'` or modify value of `$.jgrid.formatter.date.masks.ShortDate` all will be correct. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShortDate1.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Here is my demo not working http://app.intapdemo.com.ar:81/Servicios/OrdenServicios It's asp.net mvc 4 app, can you see any error?

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez: Your error is the usage of `addRowData` function. It is **low-level** method to add *any* data to the grid. The data will be added **like it be**. You should better never ever use the method. If you do use it if you have to format the data yourself. If you need fill local grid you should use `data` parameter of jqGrid. I recommend you additionally use always `gridview: true`. In your case parameters `height: 'auto'` and either the pager or `rowNum: 10000` should be added.

Comment: Thanks, I will try with the data parameter, it will be a bit more work, because I'm trying to use the data passed from asp.net mvc controller and the html is generated with a T4 template. Anyway the formatter is a bit odd, because the checkbox formatter works fine. In the jqgrid documentation for the addrowdata method should be some warning about the formatter (http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) ...

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez: I use ASP.NET MVC myself. Why you not use `datatype: 'json'`? You can easy return `JsonResult` from the controller action. The documentation of jqGrid is wiki, so you can make any modification yourself. By the way the original format of date `08/04/2012 08:42 p.m.` which you used contains wrong format of writing of `p.m.`. It should be `pm` or `PM` but not `p.m.`. You can change fix the value of `AmPm : ["am","pm","AM","PM"]` see [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/i18n/grid.locale-es.js#L102). Then you will be able to use `p.m.` and `a.m.`

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez: For better understanding. All languages files of jqGrid will be supported **by users of jqGrid** from the corresponding countries. If you open `grid.locale-es.js` for example you will see that the current contain came from Yamil Bracho user. I see that at least `ShortDate` and `AmPm` values in the `grid.locale-es.js` are wrong. So somebody should post the bug report or the puul request to fix the values.

Comment: Thanks, after using the data parameter the date formatter is working

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez: You are welcome! If you want help other jqGrid users you should post bug report to [trirand](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/) about errors in `grid.locale-es.js`.